# Delete the video being played in Video Player

Tags: windows

I have a lots of video in a folder.

Let say I select all videos and put them into a video player.

Now my question is, is there any *video player* by which I can delete the video from the directory by a shortcut-key?

Please do not say a video being played cannot be deleted :P 
Obviously if there is a video player that can do this thing, will close that video, delete it, and play the next video in playlist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PotPlayer](https://potplayer.daum.net) can do this.

You can drag and drop a bunch of files on the main window and it will start playing them in sequence.

You can then press "SHIFT+DEL" and the currently playing file will be deleted. After a file is deleted, the next one will start playing automatically.

Another useful tip: if you want to skip to the next file in the queue WITHOUT deleting it, you can do that by just pressing PGDOWN

Hope it helps

Comment: @Umair Sorry, used to the Italian keyboard, I meant DEL