# Video software that can delete or rename while watching

Tags: windows, video, file-management

I need to go through 20 hours of videos that are split up into around 5 minutes each and was hoping someone can help me find software that can view these videos and while viewing to be able to delete or rename them.

Currently, I am using the default windows 10 app which is good in that I can easily go to the next video (by clicking the arrow on the right) but when I need to delete or rename I have to go back to the file explorer, and try to find the video I was watching which takes up a lot of time especially since I have to do this hundreds of times.

If anyone knows of some software that can delete or rename while watching the video or if you have a more efficient process that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered here:
[Delete the video being played in Video Player](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19516/delete-the-video-being-played-in-video-player)

I'm using Daum PotPlayer for this too.
(Daum PotPlayer was a successor to KMPlayer. I like PotPlayer better.)
https://potplayer.daum.net/

---

Press **SHIFT+DELETE** key while playing a video on PotPlayer.

- This deletes (Recycle Bin) the currently playing video.

---

(Additional tip: **Rename video**:

- **Make sure playlist is focused: Mouse click on it** or **press F6**.
- Then **Ctrl+M**. A dialog box will pop up with the current video file name.
- Rename/change it :')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

QtTabbar file explorer starts playing a video file when you hover over it.

Comment: Your answer has been flag as low quality and might be removed; please have a look at [What is required for an answer to be high quality?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/356/23377) for some tips on how to improve it.

Comment: Please also edit your answer to include a link to the official source.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/tomek-o/VideoPlayer - rename and delete options are in the playlist/file context menu. Delete function has "D" shortcut (configurable) when playing. There is also "Go to file" if file has to be moved or something like that.